# Sum a column in my database and render it to frontend

Tags: php, laravel

I subtracted a column in my database from a form request but when I render it to frontend I see something like this (-900) so I want to remove it, I tried something like this:

```
 public function home(){
        
        
    $accounts = DB::table('accounts')->sum('trans_amou')->get();
    
    $statements = DB::table('statements')->get();
 
        //return view('home', ['accounts' => $accounts]);
        return view('home', compact('accounts', 'statements'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `get()` method after `sum()`

```
$accounts = DB::table('accounts')->sum('trans_amou');
```